# Optimize query when selecting specific prime numbers from table

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

[image: table]

I need one query which will return a result based on the following rules:

- those lines that contain more that 3 prime numbers
- those lines that contain less than 3 prime numbers
- those lines that contain between 1 and 3 prime numbers

Supposing that my table is named `numbers_table` and supposing that the table could be really large, what would be the adequate query that should be run in mysql ?

What I've done so far:

```
SELECT nr1,nr2,nr3,nr4,nr5,nr6 FROM numbers where 
  nr1 in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47) or
  nr2 in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47) or
  nr3 in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47) or
  nr4 in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47) or
  nr5 in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47) or
  nr6 in (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47);
```

Can I optimize the above solution ?

Comment: If we concatenate those 3 rules we will ger: those lines that contain any amount of prime numbers, ie you want all rows from table...

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri you're right. You can take it this way: I have to omit the lines with no prime numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really the best you can do is to create a table for primary numbers `Pnumbers(n int)`. You can easily finď all those numbers or generate ones by yorself (https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2006/09/the-prime-number-challenge-great-waste-of-time/). It is not that big set: about 80,000 in first 1,000,000 number. Having indexes on `nr` columns will work well for you. Then you can write the following select:

```
select * from tableName t
left join Pnumbers p1 on t.nr1 = p1.n
left join Pnumbers p2 on t.nr2 = p2.n
....
left join Pnumbers p6 on t.nr6 = p6.n
where p1.n is not null or p2.n is not null or ... or p6.n is not null
```

Comment: I've edited my question with my own solution. I also like your answer but it's just too complicate for the purposes that I need. I have to keep it simple. How would you optimize my solution ? Those are the prime numbers that I need so far

Comment: @Alexander, you can remove all  `and nr.. is not null`

Comment: Thanks, I'll do this. Anything that comes to your mind ? I'll mark this as accepted as it is a good answer. Don't know why 2 downvotes anyway.

Comment: @Alexander, no there is nothing to optimize. But you can check with my version and compare the performance of both. I can not really say without real testing. You may need to add indexses on rn1, ...rn6 column. That's all. It shouldn't make any problems.

Comment: how would the syntax look if id like my table to select only the rows that contain less than three prime numbers ?

Comment: `where (case when nr1 in (2, 3, ...) then 1 else 0 end + ... + case when nr6 in (2, 3, ...) then 1 else 0 end) < 3`

Comment: it works but it's also showing me the lines that does not contain any prime numbers. Any workaround ?

Comment: `where (case when nr1 in (2, 3, ...) then 1 else 0 end + ... + case when nr6 in (2, 3, ...) then 1 else 0 end) in(1, 2)`